# How to generate a simple registration code,based on input given by the user and verifying it after installation

Tags: android, registration

Suppose, I have created an android mobile application.

What I am looking for is, once the user purchases my application from my website,
he will input his IMEI number.

I want to generate a simple registration code, which can be emailed to him after purchase is successful.

The user will then enter the code in the application, application will internally fetch the IMEI number and validate the registration code.

How can I generate such registration code?

Are there algorithms/ tools available which can help me do this?

Thanks,
Aseem Chiplonkar

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are going to be developing your site in, you may want to take a look into `GUID`'s or something of that sort...Read more [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is once you have received the IMEI from the user you can apply an algorithm on it (you can, for example, shuffle the string and add some salt on it) and them generate a  [hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) of it.

Send this `hash` do the user and when he/she types this `hash` on you app you will fetch the IMEI , apply the same algorithm and calculate the `hash`. If the `hash` matches the one you sent them your app will be activated.

I would use [Sha256](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sha256), but you can also use any other hash function you like.

You can also apply a [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) algorithm to the hash to make it easier to type.