# Generate Installation key codes based on an algarithm

Tags: activation

Similar questions: [Best way to generate activation codes for software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336941/best-way-to-generate-activation-codes-for-software) and [How to generate a simple registration code,based on input given by the user and verifying it after installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468059/how-to-generate-a-simple-registration-code-based-on-input-given-by-the-user-and)

My question/use is similar to that of how Microsoft handled the All-in-One Vista disks. During the Vista install, if it did not detect a specific version to install, it asks for a keycode, then knows which version to install. My application is in Visual Basic 2010, and I would like to use keycodes to have the user unlock certain features based on what code(s) he/she has. So the code needs to be built into the software (or rather, an algorithm) so it knows what to unlock, but not be obvious enough that a black hat hacker knows that bit #*xx* unlocks feature *xxxx*. If someone posts code from another .NET or PHP, then I can translate to VB code.

My goals are to not have the codes easily guesses, and still have over 20,000 codes generated that can be converted into a set of features, plus verifying it's a unique user registering or activating the software

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In direct response to your question I would take a look at this project; it may be relevant to what you are trying to do: http://keygen.codeplex.com/

However, since you are not installing an OS and instead installing an application I would recommend using a server based DRM setup. The flow for something like this would be:

1. You generate a new key on the server and include it with the software (or send it via e-mail if it is downloadable content). Part of this generation process includes specifying the features and versions compatible with that key.
2. The user installs your software and enters the key you provided.
3. Your software checks with your registration server to see if it is a valid key and to get feature information from the server.

This solution ensures that it is impossible to modify/create new keys without access to the server. If you are using something like GUIDs on the server side then it also makes it virtually impossible to guess at a key.

Comment: That does look pretty sweet, I will check out the reverse part too. Will reply tonight